# Implementing a Generic Interface and a Non Generic Interface

Tags: c#, generics

I have two contracts (one Generic Interface and the other Non-Generic) as follows:

```
public interface IGenericContract<T>  where T : class
    {
        IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    }

public interface INonGenericContract
    {
        string GetFullName(Guid guid);
    }
```

I have a class implementing both

```
public class MyClass<T> :
        IGenericContract<T> where T : class, INonGenericContract
    {
        public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
        {
            ...
        }

        public string GetFullName(Guid guid)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Everything is fine until this point when I compile it. 
But now when I try using this class I run into this error
"error CS0311: The type 'string' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'ConsoleApplication1.MyClass'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'string' to 'ConsoleApplication1.INonGenericContract'."

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass<string> myClass = new MyClass<string>(); //Error
        }
    }
```

If I do not implement the Non-generic contract it works fine. What could be wrong here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code `INonGenericContract` is part of generic constraint, as it placed after `where`.

```
public class MyClass<T> :
    IGenericContract<T> where T : class, INonGenericContract
```

You likely want that:

```
public class MyClass<T> :
    IGenericContract<T>, INonGenericContract where T : class
```

Answer (score 4):

you are very close, what you have to do is implement the non generic interface, not put a constrain.

```
public class MyClass<T> :
    IGenericContract<T>, INonGenericContract where T : class
{
    public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public string GetFullName(Guid guid)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

now you can do this

```
MyClass<string> myClass = new MyClass<string>();
```

Answer (score 2):

According what you show

```
public class MyClass<T> : IGenericContract<T> where T : class, INonGenericContract
```

`T` must implement `INonGenericContract` and `string` doesn't implement it. In short, `string` is not a valid parameter for class `MyClass`

If what you're looking for is implementing `IGenericContract<T>` AND `INonGenericContract` you should have

```
public class MyClass<T> : INonGenericContract, IGenericContract<T>
```

there is no need to have `where T : class` since `IGenericContract<T>` already has that constraint.